# Turn filtered $_POST vars into session variables?

Tags: php, session, post

I have some variables that I am getting from a form `$_POST` array, and I am already running a lot of functions on each value `trim()` and `filter_input()`. I know that I have to add `session_start()` at the beginning of each page, and using it like this: `$_SESSION["value"]`.

I just don't know how to add my value from the post array and still use my sanitation functions on them:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$name = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
$email = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL ) );
$state = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "state", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
$zip = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "zip", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
$product_delivery = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "product_delivery", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
$facility_delivery = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "facility_delivery", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
$cc_cost = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "cc_cost", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
$labor_cost = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "labor_cost", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
$util_cost = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "util_cost", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
$total_savings = ($product_delivery - $facility_delivery - $cc_cost - $labor_cost - $util_cost);
$tons_per_year = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "tons_per_year", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
$savings_per_year = ($total_savings * $tons_per_year);
```

Can I do this? `$_SESSION[$zip]`

Comment: just do `$_SESSION['name'] = $name` Just treat it as an array.

Comment: `foreach(array('foo','bar','baz) as $x) { $_SESSION[$x] = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, $x, etc...); }`

Comment: What Marc B Said. But then again, are you sure you need all that in session? You might want to expose your design a bit deeper if you'd like further review/help :) You see, it's easy to use sessions for globals, just because it's convenient. But it's as easy to fall into antipatterns traps

Comment: Wow that's a cool solution @Marc B. So like this?   `foreach(array('ip','name','email', 'state') as $x) { $_SESSION[$x] = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, $x, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); }`

Comment: @Sebas I could post the whole page of code, but it is quite large!

Comment: @Sebas After looking at my design again, I actually don't need to carry all of these variables over. Technically Marc's answer was the best, but I have no need for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example you could do this rather than create plain variables:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = trim( filter_input( INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter_input_array()`:

```
$defs = array('name'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
              'email' => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
              //etc...

$_SESSION['data'] = array_map('trim', filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $defs));
```

I used `$_SESSION['data']` to not overwrite other session variables.  Then just access `$_SESSION['data']['name']` etc...

Or alternately:

```
$vals     = array_map('trim', filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $defs));
$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION, $vals);
```